# Creating a bar chart using ObHighchartsBundle

Tags: symfony, highcharts, bundle

I want to create using ObHighchartsBundle a bar chart(image below) but I couldnt do that the chart is rendered empty !! the problem is in the type of the chart **bar**
is that even possible using the ObHighchartsBundle

[image]

My code:

**chartingController .php :**

```
public function productionEst($date,$liste1,$liste2,$liste3)
    {
        $ob = new Highchart();
        $dates = $date;
        $production = array(
            $liste1,
            $liste2,
            $liste3
        );
        $ob->chart->type('bar');
        $ob->chart->renderTo('container');  // The #id of the div where to render the chart

        $ob->plotOptions->bar(
            array(
                'dataLabels' => array(
                    'enabled' => true
                )
            )
        );
        $ob->title->text('Production);
        $ob->xAxis->categories($dates );
        $ob->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Horizontal axis title"));
        $ob->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Vertical axis title"));
        $ob->legend->legend(
            array(
                'layout' => 'vertical',
                'align'=> 'right',
                'verticalAlign'  =>'top',
                'floating'=> true,
                'borderWidth' =>1,

                'shadow'    =>true
            )
        );





        $ob->series($production);

        return $ob;
    }
```

**index.twig :**

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 200px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    {{ chart(container) }}



</script>
```

Comment: maybe try using type column with chart.inverted set to true: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted

Comment: Do you have problems only with your bar chart? Are you able to prepare a chart with different series type?

Comment: yes  only bar chart, it works fine with line chart and stacked column

Comment: @stpoa I have tried inverted true as you have said but the same problem persist (I have tried inverted =false it works fine as column chart)

Comment: Maybe report an issue in a wrapper: https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle/issues